# Which backpropagation step is the most expensive? (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say I have a complex network that is fed with variable-sized data batches. As usual, doing backpropagation would involve essentially 3 steps:

1. Forward pass: evaluate the loss.
2. Backward pass: compute the gradient values.
3. Gradient update: compute the gradient updates with an optimizer and apply them to the variables.

In Tensorflow the tf.train.Optimizer class handles this by exposing the following methods:

- compute_gradients: applies step #1 & #2.
- apply_gradients: applies step #3.
- minimize: utility function that combines the two above (and therefore does #1, #2 & #3).

My question is, assuming we feed a big batch of data and the network is potentially deep and complex, which of these steps should be expected to be more expensive in general?

I'm asking from the distributed computing point of view. In particular, from a situation where multiple parallel instances try to contribute to one same network. For example, if computing gradients were significantly more expensive than applying them (let's say, with an AdamOptimizer), I wonder if it might be worth computing the gradients in a powerful training server, then send them to a parameter server queue that applies updates in order to avoid concurrency issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming large depth and large batch size, step 2 will be (almost exactly) twice as expensive as step 1. On the other hand, step 3 will be much cheaper than the other two.

This is an important bit to know, because it holds across many architectures (both convolutional and fully-connected).

When it doesn't hold, it's usually an implementation inefficiency / performance bug.

Answer (score 1):

The number of operations happening during the backward pass is twice the number of operations that happen during the forward pass. This is because, in the backward pass at each layer, gradients have to be calculated for the weights at that layer and for the previous layer's output (so that the gradient of the previous layer's weights can be calculated). This is twice the number of operations in a forward pass.

More details here:
https://cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc321_2017/slides/lec6.pdf

Comment: Https link doesn't work in chrome. This works: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc321_2017/slides/lec6.pdf